# Bootstrap 3 dropdown navbar

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using the bootstrap example to do the navigation bar with a dropdown.  If I am on my site's homepage and I click the dropdown it works fine.  Then I choose the first sublink and it opens.  Then when I click on the dropdown again it adds # to the end of the link in the url and the dropdown does not work, the link then looks like this:

```
http://domain/report.php#

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Reviews <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="report.php">Latest Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Perhaps because that `report.php` page hasn't the link to `bootstrap.js` and/or `bootstrap.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `report.php` page hasn't the link to `bootstrap.js` and/or `bootstrap.css?`